# Is childish behaviour OK at workplaces?

Tags: professionalism, workplace-rhythm

Is excitement and childish behavior ok if I am a hard worker? Does it impact my career even if there are no obstacles in way of working and it does not effect my productivity? I complete all my assignments & tasks on time.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about regulations or agreements that are company-specific and don't have universally applicable answers.

Comment: Specifically, this depends very much on the culture where you work. I love working in startups because I can be childish at times and nobody will think badly of me. When I worked in insurance brokerage, childishness was largely a no-go, even though it was a very progressive team.

Comment: What's your question here? This sounds like a rant and does not really have a specific, answerable question right now. The answer basically depends on "what is childish behavior" as well as "what is your company culture" and "what cultural norms do you have."

Comment: I liked the question, but it needs to be more specific. Exemplify what you consider a childish behavior.

Answer (score 7):

IMHO, one of the most important things in a workplace/career is the ability to understand your environment AS WELL as completing all your assignments and tasks on time. You need to be able to judge an office/workplace and know what is and is not acceptable based on your colleagues, managers, clients. Just being able to do the work will get you so far but understanding your environment is just as important

I am in no way saying you just need to blend in, but knowing what is and isnlt acceptable is your responsibility and should be an inate skill.

High fiving the person sat next to you when you've just secured a multi million pound sale may be acceptable. High fiving the manager because you just found out he's sleeping with his secretary may not.

You probably want to extend your question to give an example of the excitement and childish behaviour

Answer (score 1):

If you are working you are an adult and you should leave childish behavior behind. Yes it can affect your career. There are many things of far more of importance to the workplace if you want to get pay raises or promotions or stay employed than just doing your work on time which is after all the minimal expectation.

So since you didn't give any examples of the childish behavior I can give some and how I might expect most comapnies to respond.

Tantrums - you usually can only get away with these if you are in a high power position. So the CEO or  the VP can have a tantrum but the average worker cannot.

Excitement  - usually enthusiasm is considered ok. However, you need to tone it down if the other employees are not receacting similarly.

Whining about doing things you don't want to do - Generally gets you labeled as uncooperative and will result in lower pay raises and fewer opportuinituies to do the interesting work and will reduce chances of promotion. No one like s working with a whiner, so they won't put you into the best positions unless you havea skill no one else has and they can't find someone to replace you. This execption would apply to far less than 1% of the workforce.

Ignoring manager instructions because you don't want to do the task or want to do things your own way- A quick route to getting fired most places.

Ignoring workplace administrative rules you don't like including doing timesheets or coming in late. Making your manager find you annoying is usually not a smart move in the workplace. You have to be extra special to avoid having this stuff come back to haunt you in many workplaces. You may get away with this for awhile, but you will be first on the lay off list and get lower payraises and performance appraisals many places. If the only thing the manager ever hears about you is that you didn;t do something, then he already has a negative imporession of you and you wil have to work twice as hard to erase it.

Playing games instead of working - only works long term if you are really, really far more productive than anyone else in the group or have a naive manager. The smart manager will see that you need to have far more work assigned to you and make sure it happens. There are some start-ups where this is acceptable behavior, but this often changes once they start to grow up and be a big company. A few tech companies manage to retain this, but not many and almost never in any other business sector.

Answer (score 1):

It entirely depends on what's acceptable at your work-place, and if the behaviour is detrimental or seen by customers. Overall, just know that there's a big difference between being childish and being fun - the former being unacceptable.

Using myself as an example, I'm one of the individuals who always gets introduced to customers because I'm by far the most professionally-presented people in my office, but at the same time I'm the 'fun' guy at the office.

We have whiteboards which I draw quick cartoons, I've designed entire 'gag' posters and hung them in my managers office (one of which featuring slugs attempting to use our products), I entertain my co-workers - and they all love it; 10/10 tone and demeanour every review. They tell me every time I'm the bar for T'n'D.

What's important is to keep work first, and I know what's appropriate when. Everyone knows that if I'm going to a meeting or working it's time to be serious. If you have something to be doing then do it first and foremost. Be professional and courteous, don't do anything that impacts someone elses ability to work. Know that you're being paid to do a job, so keep it to your breaks and off the clock.

Overall, I think it's important that you do everything you can to keep the environment positive and professional. If you have 10 extra seconds to brighten someone day then do it! But anything more is too much; know the difference between being fun and being childish.